# SendGrid is always sending my emails to the Spam folder of the recipient

Tags: email, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email from my [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) using the SendGrid's mail [client for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail)

I am following their example described as follows:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(functions.config().sendgrid.key);
const msg = {
  to: 'my_own_mail@gmail.com',
  from: 'my_other_own_mail@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

Once the function is fired, everything gets executed successfully. In my function logs I get **Status 202** and the actual mail gets delivered but not in the main mailbox but rather in the Spam folder. When I open the message, it simply says:

[image]

I don't really understand what is the problem.

**NOTE**: If I send the message to an Yahoo email it doesn't go in the Spam folder. Same applies if I send it to my business email.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to cloud functions or the code, there are a few anti-spam rules you need to follow, [this gave me a good starting point](https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/)

Comment: I already covered that document but it is quite big to cover everything in it. I find it strange being able to deliver regular emails using https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/ without any problem but struggling with SendGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Sendgrid does not send your messages to the SPAM folder it all depends on the recipients  mail delivery flow spam filters.

Most messages are marked as spam for one of the following reasons

**1. Message is not authenticated properly**

Validated that your message is authenticated properly with [SPF](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en) or [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)

**2.Your message originates from an IP that is in a Blacklist (this might be on Sendgrid's)**

Try by sending a message to your self and open the [message headers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en) , then look for entries like the one below

```
Received: from xxxxxxxxx.com (xxxxxxx.com [xxx.xx.xxx.xx])
        by xxxx.com with SMTPS id ##############
```

The IP between [] is the sending server IP try to use public blacklist such as [spamhaus](https://www.spamhaus.org/) to see if it is blacklisted and report to Sendrig if you find a match

**3.The content of your message has known phishing techniques (accidentally or not)**

Check the "Format your mail" section for [Gmail senders guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en) as general recommendation

Comment: Regarding the second reason: I did exactly what you said, and then I picked the IP and entered it here https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/ Then I got the following result: https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/107.178.236.16

Comment: I also edited my question. I hope it gives more information about my issue with SendGrid. I have the feeling it is Gmail specific.

Comment: A match in XBL means the connecting machine is either an open proxy or a spam-sending Trojan Horse. Email services such as Sendgrid tend to use the same pool of IPs for all customers unless you request your own IP (extra cost) you should report your finding to Sendgrid.

Comment: Just noticed that both sender and recipient are gmail users. Gmail has one of the most advanced spam filters most likely the IP being in a black list (with another condition) is automatically marking the message as spam. ask the recipients to mark your messages as not spam and this will teach Gmail filters because user feedback is taken into consideration, I would purse the report with Sendgrid as this is a really bad signal for Gmail filters

Comment: I was told by SendGrid's support that this type of account shares an IP pool and if some of the users got reported for using one of the IPs in the pool, the whole set of users in this set suffers. They told me that if I move to a higher (paid) plan I would have my own dedicated IP and this would solve the problem. Most probably..